# Why is .delay() not iterating properly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using `d3.v4.min.js` to generate the bar chart in the snippet below.
For some unknown reason, the `transition().delay()` function is behaving weird. 
I pass as argument the function `(d,i)=>{return i*100}` to cause each column to wait a multiple of 100 milliseconds before starting the animation. At least, that is what I expected to happen, since `i`'s value should be `0,1,2,...etc`.

However, all columns start the animation at once, and I have traced the root cause to `i` in `dealy()` function. It is fixed to zero in all iterations.

What mistake did I do?

```js
//jshint esnext:true

const margin = {top: 30, bottom: 70, left: 40, right: 10};
const width = 600, height=200;
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
const data = [{name:'ahmad',age:22},
              {name:'saleh',age:15},
              {name:'fulan',age:35},
              {name:'fazil',age:48},
              {name:'majid',age:50}
             ];
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width",width)
              .attr("height",height)
              .style("background-color","beige");

const max = d3.max(data,d=>{return d.age;});
const min = 0; //1 || d3.min(data,d=>{return d.age;});
const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min,max]).range([height-margin.bottom,margin.top]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);

const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d=>{return d.name;}))
            .range([margin.left,width-margin.right])
            .padding(0.4);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);

svg.append("g").attr("class","y axis").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+",0)").call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("class","x axis").attr("transform","translate(0,"+(height-margin.bottom)+")").call(xAxis);

const selection = svg.selectAll(".name").data(data);
const enter = selection.enter().append("g").attr("class","name");
const exit = selection.exit();

enter.append("rect").attr("x",d=>{return x(d.name);}).attr("y",y(0)).attr("width",x.bandwidth()).attr("height",0).attr("fill",d=>{return color(d.name);});



// here is the problem. I can't figure out why animation is not delayed per iteration.
enter.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay((d,i)=>{
         /*console.log(i);*/  // this prints 0 for all iterations. Why?  
         return 100*i;
       })
      .duration(1000)
      .ease(d3.easeElastic)
     .attr("y",d=>{return y(d.age);})
     .attr("height",d=>{return y(0)-y(d.age);});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `enter` is a selection of `<g>` elements, each one having just one `<rect>`. So, use `select` instead of `selectAll`:

```
enter.select("rect")
    //etc...
```

Here is your modified code:

```js
//jshint esnext:true

const margin = {top: 30, bottom: 70, left: 40, right: 10};
const width = 600, height=200;
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
const data = [{name:'ahmad',age:22},
              {name:'saleh',age:15},
              {name:'fulan',age:35},
              {name:'fazil',age:48},
              {name:'majid',age:50}
             ];
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width",width)
              .attr("height",height)
              .style("background-color","beige");

const max = d3.max(data,d=>{return d.age;});
const min = 0; //1 || d3.min(data,d=>{return d.age;});
const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min,max]).range([height-margin.bottom,margin.top]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);

const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d=>{return d.name;}))
            .range([margin.left,width-margin.right])
            .padding(0.4);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);

svg.append("g").attr("class","y axis").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+",0)").call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("class","x axis").attr("transform","translate(0,"+(height-margin.bottom)+")").call(xAxis);

const selection = svg.selectAll(".name").data(data);
const enter = selection.enter().append("g").attr("class","name");
const exit = selection.exit();

enter.append("rect").attr("x",d=>{return x(d.name);}).attr("y",y(0)).attr("width",x.bandwidth()).attr("height",0).attr("fill",d=>{return color(d.name);});



// here is the problem. I can't figure out why animation is not delayed per iteration.
enter.select("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay((d,i)=>{
         /*console.log(i);*/  // this prints 0 for all iterations. Why?  
         return 100*i;
       })
      .duration(1000)
      .ease(d3.easeElastic)
     .attr("y",d=>{return y(d.age);})
     .attr("height",d=>{return y(0)-y(d.age);});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Just for you to understand the differences between `select` and `selectAll` (more on the table below), you can use `selectAll`, but not with the `enter` selection. For instance:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    //etc...
```

Here it is:

```js
const margin = {top: 30, bottom: 70, left: 40, right: 10};
const width = 600, height=200;
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
const data = [{name:'ahmad',age:22},
              {name:'saleh',age:15},
              {name:'fulan',age:35},
              {name:'fazil',age:48},
              {name:'majid',age:50}
             ];
const svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
              .attr("width",width)
              .attr("height",height)
              .style("background-color","beige");

const max = d3.max(data,d=>{return d.age;});
const min = 0; //1 || d3.min(data,d=>{return d.age;});
const y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min,max]).range([height-margin.bottom,margin.top]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y);

const x = d3.scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map(d=>{return d.name;}))
            .range([margin.left,width-margin.right])
            .padding(0.4);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);

svg.append("g").attr("class","y axis").attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+",0)").call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("class","x axis").attr("transform","translate(0,"+(height-margin.bottom)+")").call(xAxis);

const selection = svg.selectAll(".name").data(data);
const enter = selection.enter().append("g").attr("class","name");
const exit = selection.exit();

enter.append("rect").attr("x",d=>{return x(d.name);}).attr("y",y(0)).attr("width",x.bandwidth()).attr("height",0).attr("fill",d=>{return color(d.name);});


// here is the problem. I can't figure out why animation is not delayed per iteration.
svg.selectAll("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay((d,i)=>{
         /*console.log(i);*/  // this prints 0 for all iterations. Why?  
         return 100*i;
       })
      .duration(1000)
      .ease(d3.easeElastic)
     .attr("y",d=>{return y(d.age);})
     .attr("height",d=>{return y(0)-y(d.age);});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**Table:** Differences between `select` and `selectAll`.

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

Comment: That really solved my problem.  read your answer again, and edited my comment. Thanks I will be able to accept your answer after a while, btw

Comment: @Ahmad I added another example with `selectAll`. Did you understand the difference?

Comment: This makes sense now. Much appreciated